# jquery button click event in cshtml page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to mvc so not sure how we can handle button click event on client side using mvc application and jquery. I want to write some jquery code for button click event but dn't know exactly where to put this in cshtml page. Below is my code :

```
<p> 
 <input type="button" value="Create" id="btnSave"/>
</p>
    (at the bottom of cshtml page)  :
    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Owner.js")
    }
```

And in Owner.js which I have included above, the code is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btnSave').click(function () {
        alert('click');

    });
});
```

But i am not able to get the pop up message as "Click" on button click as I have coded. Please correct me if i have done something wrong.

Comment: Check your browser console for any errors

Comment: do you have jquery refered in your code?

Comment: there is no error.. i have checked it previoulsy

Comment: You didn't include jquery library file. please download and check

Comment: check the loaded javascript files and javascript errors

Comment: yes in bundle config, i have included jquery lib files as jquery-1.8.2.js

Comment: i have also edited code above so that there is no confusion.

Comment: Can you put the bundle configuration for @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery")?

Comment: yes i have double checked it.. files are there in directory. but still not able to replicate the error. .. even if i write the jquery code within script tag(without bundle configuration) its not working.

Comment: @Ala here is the bundle configuration: public class BundleConfig
    {

        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")
              
            );
          
        }
    }

Comment: You must check page source and see if scripts are being rendered on page or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i loaded jquery through online link then it was working fine. no idea but may be there was some problem in my version of jquery. but my workaround was using layout.cshtml and rendering all the needed files from there only except the owner.js file.

anyways.. thanks everyone for your time and help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the owner.js and jquery library files exist in the actual file for your project and not just the solution explorer? Visual Studio won't throw any errors if you have them in the solution explorer, but it can cause bugs if they are not actually in the file. Also since you are using relative paths make sure that those paths match up with where the files are in your actual project folder. Sometimes Visual Studio will say theres a file in a location in the solution explorer but in actuality it just hasn't been updated to show where it really is on the drive. That's all I can think, I had similar trouble with a JavaScript slider and that is what my problem was. Best of luck, hope this helps!

Comment: yes i have double checked it.. files are there in directory. but still not able to replicate the error. .. even if i write the jquery code within script tag its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same code but with out `@section Scripts` block. So its working fine. (Also I have used the latest version of JQuery)

```
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Create" id="btnSave" />
</div>
```

(at the bottom of cshtml page)

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Owner.js")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if you have added Owner.js in your bundle.config and then include

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Owner.js")
```

Click event is not getting fired so might be some small issue like this so check if your browser is showing all scripts needed by debugging your code.